# Assign weight to attribute based on there value is grater or lesser then some value: algolia

Tags: algolia

Hi I am trying to find a search solution where I can assign a weight (x point) to an attribute if its value is greater or smaller then some value ( Y value)

Like if the price is greater then 10 USD then assign 5 points to the item, and I am assigning points on multiple attribute, then get the list of item on the bases of total points in asc or desc order, how can i do this in algolia

Answer (score 0):

Algolia doesn't work with weights, but with a tie-breaking strategy that decides how to rank results based on their attributes. This strategy is static, and set at indexing time.

In your case, you're willing to rank results by a multitude of criteria, including by price. The easiest way to do this is to use the [`customRanking`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/customRanking/) attribute and set each attribute that should play a role in the ranking strategy. For example, if you want more expensive items to be ranked higher, you can do the following (JavaScript example, but you have a choice between 11 different languages):

```js
index.setSettings({
  customRanking: [
    'desc(price)'
  ]
});
```

Notice the `customRanking` property takes an array. You can pass several criteria for your custom ranking, and they will be taken into account in the defined order, if the engine can't break the tie.

Since you're working with prices, you may end up in a case where two prices are so close that it makes no sense to break the tie on them; and you'll want to move on to the next criterion. In this case, you can add a new attribute with a rounded price and use this one as the custom ranking attribute. There's a [guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/must-do/custom-ranking/how-to/controlling-custom-ranking-metrics-precision/) in the documentation on that topic.